# altering them for node edit page not working

Tags: forms, theming

I got the following to work by adding it to the admin template.php file. But I am not having any luck changing the one edit form to use boostrap_subtheme vs the default admin theme. Any advice with that? To add a little more to this, I am using the following code to set the add node for data set to the default theme, how would you do this for a node edit page?  The url for the node edit page contains the node id.

function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
    $items['node/add/data-set']['theme callback'] = 'mm_get_default_theme';

}

function mm_get_default_theme(){
    return variable_get('theme_default', '0');
}

I am using the [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_theme/7) function to override the theme for a given node's edit form. This works when you create a new node but does not override the theme with the use clicks "edit". Any ideas? Path of the edit form is for instance `node/39/edit`.

```
$items['custom_node_form'] = array(
  'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
  'render element' => 'form',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'bootstrap_subtheme') . '/templates',
  'template' => 'custom-node-form',    
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working on my site, although i haven't made a template but it should work with a template too. here is my code

```
function modulename_theme(){
     $items['article_node_form'] = array(
    'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    'render element' => 'form',
  );
    return $items;
}
function theme_article_node_form(&$var){
    $form=$var['form'];
    $output = '<h2>' . t('Please enter your information below') . '</h2>';
    $output .= drupal_render_children($form);
    return $output;

}
```

Comment: If I change the admin theme to be bootstrap_subtheme it will work but I only want this one form to be changed to the boostrap them.